# unexpected error of "control may reach end of a non void function"

Tags: c

I write a program to sum the elements in an array. However, when I am compiling the program, it tells me that "control  may reach end of a non void function". I don't know why.

```
//a program to sum the elements of an array

#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int array[],int n)
{
int sum =0, *ptr;
int *arrayend=array +n;
for(ptr=array; ptr<arrayend;++array)
{
    sum +=*ptr;
    return sum;
}
}

int main(void)
{
int sum(int array[],int n);
int value[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
printf("The sum is %i\n",sum(value,10));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Place `return sum;` outside of `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `sum()` is poorly formed and let's say the for loop condition fails at first attempt and you never enter the loop then you have a situation where you are not returning anything and your function return type is `int`

So this case needs to be addressed so that even if you fail to enter the loop there should be return after the loop.

return within a loop makes no sense unless there is a condition based on which you return.

Answer (score 0):

You try to `return sum` each time the loop body is executed, but functions only return **once**. So on the first iteration of the loop the function will return. That's the same as having no loop.

You need to put `return sum` *after* the loop, so that your loop makes sense. I.e. **first** add `*ptr` to `sum` *n* times, **then** return the resulting `sum`.

Also, in the loop you do `++array`. That should probably be `++ptr`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, after i put the `return sum` outside the for loop and run the program, it does not generate any output jut blank and blank.

Comment: It's because you increment `array`, while you should be incrementing `ptr`.

Comment: Oh, I get that. Thanks